# how do i consume model in BL to controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am implementing loosely coupled architecture. 
MVC as Presentation layer(ProjectName.Web) and all the Business Logic will be handled in a seperate C# project ProjectName.BL.

I will be consuming the webservice from my BL layer(ProjectName.BL). So the requestparameter class objects will be visible to BL since i am making servicereference.

1) The issue i am facing is how will i send my request parameter from Controller to BL layer. 
2) Next issue is how will map the ViewModel objects in BL once i get response from service, as the viewmodels are in my web projects.

Request your assistance i have no clue to achieve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is like any other question on layering and separation of concerns.

Use a DTO. In your Business Layer, introduce types for performing the action you want to perform, and perform mapping between types.

Your question isn't quite concrete, so I'll go with Foo:

Service Layer:

```
public class ServiceFooRequest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceFooResponse
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public ServiceFooResponse GetFoo(ServiceFooRequest request)
{
    return new ServiceFooResponse
    {
        Bar = "Baz"
    };
}
```

Business Layer:

```
public class BLFooResponse
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class BLL
{
    public BLFooResponse GetFoo(int id)
    {
        var serviceResponse = _serviceReferenceClient.GetFoo(new ServiceFooRequest
        {
            ID = id
        });

        return new BLFooResponse
        {
            Bar = serviceResponse.Bar
        };
    }
}
```

MVC:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult GetFoo(int id)
{
    var businessFooResponse = _bll.GetFoo(id);
    var fooViewModel = new FooViewModel
    {
        Bar = businessFooResponse.Bar
    };      
    return View(fooViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the above solution solved my second issue. How will i send the request parameters from controller to BL as an object and not like Int id,string 'vin',decimal 12.00. So the object will map to Service request parameter to invoke the service

Answer (score 0):

You need separate project (DLL) Models. It will store shared between layers models.
Each controller should have reference to BL object or BLL factory.
Hint - use Automapper to copy DAO objects to BDO.

Web project

```
public class FoodController : BaseController
{
    private IFoodBll _foodBll = null;

    public FoodController(IFoodBll foodBll)
    {
        // Make DI of your BLL
        _foodBll = foodBll;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(FoodEditModel model)
    {
        _foodBll.Save(model);
    }
```

Your Edit.cshtml should look smth like this

```
@model MyProjects.Web.Models.Foods.FoodEditModel

@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Id)
@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Name)
```

Comment: Could you please let me know an example or a link where will get to know clear picture. The constraint in my current architecture is,  i cannot introduce any layer